# Diificulty using Range Datepicker jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on a website and I wanted to add a range date picker form. As I am doing that I keep on getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null"

I tried everything and searched everywhere but couldn't find any solution. I get the same error while trying to incorporate the auto-complete google maps plugin as well.

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" name="datarange"/>
</div>
```

The above is the HTML where I am using the datepicker.

```
<script>
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
</script>
```

The above is the script tag.

I am getting the source code and documentation from http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a document.ready event handler, `$(function() { /* your code here... */ });`

Comment: 1.Make sure that jQuery library and then date-picker library added .2. wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..//your code..});`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Both the jQuery library and the date-picker library are added and i tried your suggestion as well but still the same error

Comment: @Harun  i am not able to see any `'firstChild'` related code in your given data.Where it was?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').daterangepicker({});
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" name="datarange"/>
</div>
```

Please check the Query selector and the library you have added properly

and check the code below working. 
thanks hope code might help you. 
Check this link [Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/akit/grdjvobz/)